# Cannot delete content type - possibly because it's referenced in SharePoint's UI

Tags: content-type, delete, recycle-bin

I created a content type to play around with. I created a publishing page based on this content type, but after deleting the page (and clearing the recycling bin) SharePoint won't let me delete it.

```
The content type is in use.
```

After some investigation, I ran the following PowerShell code which would tell me where the content type is being used.

```
$site = Get-SPSite("http://mySite");
foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs) {
   $ctype = $web.ContentTypes["Test-publishing-page-parent"]
   $usages = [Microsoft.Sharepoint.SPContentTypeUsage]::GetUsages($ctype)
   foreach ($usage in $usages) {
      Write-Host $usage.Url
   }
}
```

The output was `/Pages`

There are no more pages that exist in the Pages collection (or the recylcing bin) that reference the content type.

[image]

However, I did notice that the "New Document" selection drop down contains references to this content type (and others!). In fact, it seems that I cannot delete any custom content types that are referenced in this selection drop down, even though they are not used anywhere else. Any ideas? Is this a possible bug in SharePoint 2013?

[image]

*Note: Yes, I've already cleared the recycling bin several times, at the site level and the site collection level.*

SharePoint 2013 on-premise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The content type was added to the available content types for your Pages Library. Go to **Pages > Library ribbon > Library settings > Content types section**. Click on the content type name there and then delete.

That will remove it from the Pages library. Then you can go into Site Settings > Content Types and delete it there.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm going to have to try out that PowerShell it looks useful.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find the problem and the solution.

It all started when I wanted to create a site template from a subsite. When attempting to use the template, SharePoint threw an error saying that there was a duplicate content type. It was not possible simply to delete the duplicate content type because another error was reported, something like "is still in use".

Faced with a lot of research, delete and restore my lists and some scripts later, I decided to delete all items from the "Tasks" list, which in my case was the list where the content type was associated. After that, I was able to remove it from the list and then permanently delete it from the site.

Well, this was done in a QA environment. I suggest making a back up plan before deleting items and lists.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you think that because you deleted all items of that content type and removed all references from all lists/document libraries, there are no more references, but you may be forgetting about the recycle bin, and there are two of them: the site and the site collection. These won't show up in the references that you get using the API. You can empty them using the UI or through the API:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() =>
{
    using (var site = new SPSite("https://my.site"))
    {
        var query = new SPRecycleBinQuery();
        //for first-level, site recycle bin, uncomment this line
        //query.ItemState = SPRecycleBinItemState.FirstStageRecycleBin;
        query.ItemState = SPRecycleBinItemState.SecondStageRecycleBin;

        var items = site.GetRecycleBinItems(query);

        foreach (var item in items.OfType<SPRecycleBinItem>())
        {
            item.Delete();
        }
    }
});
```

After this, you can try deleting the content type programmatically:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() =>
{
    using (var site = new SPSite("https://my.site"))
    {
        var web = site.RootWeb;
        var ctype = web.ContentTypes["MyContentType"];
        ctype.Delete();
    }
});
```

Hope this helps!